# How to insert values in table if there is a primary key on id field in it?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I have trouble, I have table named my_table)

```
id name
1 A
2 B
3 C
```

and I want to insert top 2 so, values have autoincrement automaticaly like this

```
insert into my_table (name) values (A), (B);
```

Is this possible in postgressql?

May be I should have count(*) + 1, then count(*) + 2 here

```
insert into my_table (id, name) values (count(*) + 1, A), (count(*) + 2, B);
```

or something like this
because my id has constraint

```
BIGSEREIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
```

And I cant add values without getting the last id in table.

Comment: If `id` is defined as `bigserial` then your first INSERT statement will do exactly what you want

Comment: You'd probably get ID 1 for A and ID 2 for B automatically, when your table is empty, but I don't think this is guaranteed with your multi row insert statement. You'd have to run two statements instead to ensure A gets a lower ID then B: `insert into my_table (name) values (A);`, then `insert into my_table (name) values (B);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
create table my_table (
  id int not null generated always as identity,
  name varchar(10) not null
);

insert into my_table (name) values ('A'), ('B');
```

Then:

```
select * from my_table;
```

Result:

```
id  name
--  ----
 1  A   
 2  B
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=53a86e11bc889c432fc93da5367d1ace).